# Find the index of max value in a 3D array and store as 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D array of shape 7x10000x10000 . The first dimension of the array is a vector of length 7. I want to create a 2D array, of shape 10000x10000, that has the the index of max element in the vector. I tried doing it using loops but it s very slow because of the size of the array. Is there any better way of doing it , like flatten, find max in each vector and reshape?

```
    for i in range(0,7):
    for j in range(0,10000):
        for k in range(0,10000):
            vector = myarray[:,j,k]
            m = np.argmax(vector) 
            img[j,k] = m
```

Comment: there's always a better solution

Comment: `myarray.argmax(0)`?

Comment: did you try the axis parameter of argmax?

Comment: @hpaulj I haven't tried the axis parameter. Let me try that.

Comment: @Divakar I will also try argmax(0)